# Override TreeTableCell rendering in JavaFX

Tags: javafx-2

I am trying to change the rendering of a TextFieldTreeTableCell to show a string as a Hyperlink as opposed to plaintext, to no avail. It seems as though it should be doable using setSkin, but something like

setSkin((new HyperLink()).getSkin());

or

setSkin((new HyperLink(getItem())).getSkin());

does not help. Any insight on how this could be done?

Comment: I would like to display a non-editable, clickable URL.

Answer (score 1):

*What you are doing wrong*

1. You are not using the right function to customize your cell: [setSkin](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Control.html#setSkin-javafx.scene.control.Skin-) is is used for creating custom control skins and is generic to all kinds of controls not just cells, you should a use a cell factory instead.
2. You are not using the right superclass: TextFieldTreeTableCell is for creating a cell which contains a label that can be made into an editable TextField when you click on it.  Such functionality is not useful when you want to "display a non-editable, clickable URL".

*Approach you should use*

Cells have a specific method for controlling their rendering which is preferred to the skin mechanism when working with cells.  This cell specific mechanism is called a cell factory and is documented with an example in the [Cell documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Cell.html).

[TreeTableColumns](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeTableColumn.html) allow you to [set a cell factory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeTableColumn.html#setCellFactory-javafx.util.Callback-) on the column to control the rendering of the column cells.  The relevant code for rendering a Hyperlink in a cell is below:

```
emailColumn.setCellFactory(param -> new TreeTableCell<Employee, String>() {
    private Hyperlink link = new Hyperlink();
    {
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (item == null || empty) {
            setGraphic(null);
            return;
        }

        link.setText(item);
        link.setVisited(getTreeTableRow().getItem().isVisited());
        link.setOnAction(event -> {
            getTreeTableRow().getItem().setVisited(true);
            sendLabel.setText("Send mail to: " + item);
        });
        setGraphic(link);
    }
});
```

*Sample Application*

In the screen shot below, the user has just linked on the hyperlink for `anna.black@example.com`.

[image: sample view]

The sample code is a modified version of the code from the [Oracle TreeTableView tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/tree-table-view.htm).  The addition of a visited property to the Employee class is necessary to keep track of which items in the TreeTableView have been clicked on, so that the Hyperlink [visited](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Hyperlink.html#visitedProperty) property can be appropriately set when the cell is updated.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.image.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.*;

public class TreeTableViewSample extends Application {

    private List<Employee> employees = Arrays.asList(
        new Employee("Ethan Williams", "ethan.williams@example.com"),
        new Employee("Emma Jones", "emma.jones@example.com"),
        new Employee("Michael Brown", "michael.brown@example.com"),
        new Employee("Anna Black", "anna.black@example.com"),
        new Employee("Rodger York", "roger.york@example.com"),
        new Employee("Susan Collins", "susan.collins@example.com"));

    private final ImageView depIcon = new ImageView (
            new Image("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/flatastic-10/16/Bear-icon.png")
    );

    final TreeItem<Employee> root = 
        new TreeItem<>(new Employee("Sales Department", ""), depIcon);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(TreeTableViewSample.class, args);
    }

    final Label sendLabel = new Label();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        root.setExpanded(true);
        employees.forEach((employee) -> root.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<>(employee)));
        stage.setTitle("Tree Table View Sample");
        final Scene scene = new Scene(new VBox(), 400, 400);
        scene.setFill(Color.LIGHTGRAY);
        VBox sceneRoot = (VBox) scene.getRoot();

        TreeTableColumn<Employee, String> empColumn = 
            new TreeTableColumn<>("Employee");
        empColumn.setPrefWidth(150);
        empColumn.setCellValueFactory(
            (TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Employee, String> param) -> 
            new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(param.getValue().getValue().getName())
        );

        TreeTableColumn<Employee, String> emailColumn = 
            new TreeTableColumn<>("Email");
        emailColumn.setPrefWidth(190);
        emailColumn.setCellValueFactory(
            (TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Employee, String> param) -> 
            new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(param.getValue().getValue().getEmail())
        );
        emailColumn.setCellFactory(param -> new TreeTableCell<Employee, String>() {
            private Hyperlink link = new Hyperlink();
            {
                setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
            }

            @Override
            protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);

                if (item == null || empty) {
                    setGraphic(null);
                    return;
                }

                link.setText(item);
                link.setVisited(getTreeTableRow().getItem().isVisited());
                link.setOnAction(event -> {
                    getTreeTableRow().getItem().setVisited(true);
                    sendLabel.setText("Send mail to: " + item);
                });
                setGraphic(link);
            }
        });

        TreeTableView<Employee> treeTableView = new TreeTableView<>(root);
        treeTableView.getColumns().setAll(empColumn, emailColumn);
        sceneRoot.getChildren().addAll(treeTableView, sendLabel);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public class Employee {
        private SimpleStringProperty name;
        private SimpleStringProperty email;
        private SimpleBooleanProperty visited;

        public SimpleStringProperty nameProperty() {
            if (name == null) {
                name = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "name");
            }
            return name;
        }
        public SimpleStringProperty emailProperty() {
            if (email == null) {
                email = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "email");
            }
            return email;
        }
        private Employee(String name, String email) {
            this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
            this.email = new SimpleStringProperty(email);
            this.visited = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name.get();
        }
        public void setName(String fName) {
            name.set(fName);
        }
        public String getEmail() {
            return email.get();
        }
        public void setEmail(String fName) {
            email.set(fName);
        }

        public void setVisited(boolean visited) {
            this.visited.set(visited);
        }

        public boolean isVisited() {
            return visited.get();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see now! Thanks :)